# cursor function to avoid repetition in sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, android-sqlite

I have a sqlite Database, which contains transport stations, i duplicated some stations in the database because they are in different lines, so i used a cursor :

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    float[] results = new float[1];
    Database db = new Database(Stations.this);
    try {
        db.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new Error("unable to create database");
    }
    try {
        db.openDataBase();
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        throw sqle;
    }
    Cursor c = db.query("Stations", null, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Location.distanceBetween(latitude, longitude, c.getDouble(4), c.getDouble(3), results);
            if (results[0] < 1000) {
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(c.getDouble(4), c.getDouble(3))).title(c.getString(1) + " " + c.getString(2)));
                Toast.makeText(this, "nearby station "+ " " + c.getString(2) + "\n", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
        while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    if (googleMap != null) {
        LatLng googleLocation = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(googleLocation));
    }
}
```

This displays the stations but duplicated if the station is mentioned twice in the database, how can i handle this and not show a station that has already been seen knowing that the 2stations have differennt id's but same names??

Comment: What are the names of the columns of the table?

Comment: @forpas 0 station id, 1 station type (bus,subway etc..), 2 station name, 3 longitude, 4 latitude, 5 lign id. when for example station X is repeated in the database, the two records have the same caracteristics but not the same id station so i must do something so that when the cursor finds a record with the same station name, it will not display it, help!

Comment: Are the station names unique?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` in your query:

```
select s.* from stations s 
where not exists (
  select 1 from stations 
  where station_name = s.station_name and station_id < s.station_id
)
```

Replace:

```
Cursor c = db.query("Stations", null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

with:

```
String sql = "select s.* from stations s where not exists (select 1 from stations where station_name = s.station_name and station_id < s.station_id)";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
```